# HTML line break doesn't execute a line break

Tags: html, css, newline

I am working on a text-based game, and in part of the text, it doesn't create a new line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
      body {
        background-color: black;
      }
      p {
        color: white;
        font-family: "Courier";
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 30em;
        animation: type 4s steps(60, end);
      }


      @keyframes type{
        from { width: 0; }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="one">Welcome, unsuspectful human. \nWhat is your name?</p> 

  </body>
</html>
```

But the outcome is this:

```
Welcome, unsuspectful human. \nWhat is your name?
```

For some reason, `\n` doesn't make the extra line. I would have separate `<p>`'s but the text appears at the same time? I don't really know how to explain it.

Here is the page I have: https://codepen.io/superduperamazing/pen/bGoOXjr

Comment: HTML line break is `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br />` tag instead

```
  <body>
    <p class="one">Welcome, unsuspectful human. <br /> What is your name?</p> 
  </body>
```

Comment: The letters pop up one at a time, and I want the "what is your name" part to pop up _after_ the "welcome" part. But with the ```<br />``` tag, it doesn't do that

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to add a line break depending on your use case...

```
<br /> HTML line break element
\n end-of-line Unix-like systems
\r\n end-of-line in Windows
```

If this is strictly web based then use <br />

Comment: That didn't seem to work. it's still one line. I'm trying to get one line at a time.

Comment: Look at this link: https://codepen.io/superduperamazing/pen/bGoOXjr

Answer (score 0):

If every line is a `<p>` you could use Javascript to add the animation class after each line.

HTML

```
<p>Welcome, unsuspectful human.</p>
<p>What is your name?</p>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  display: none;
}

.write {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end);
}

@keyframes type {
  from { width: 0; }
}
```

JS

```
writeLine(0);

function writeLine(lineNumber) {
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll("p"); 
  elements[lineNumber].classList.add("write");
  
  if(lineNumber < elements.length-1) {
     // I didn't use a forEach because then the timeouts would all be set together
     setTimeout(function(){writeLine(lineNumber+1)}, 3500);
  }
}
```